# Angular2 and Webpack bootstraping

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I've recently started learning Angular2 and since I already knew a bit of Webpack I wanted to use them together. I followed some guides and tutorials online to come up with a rather simple app the only problem I now face is that I can't actually run it. I think I've done everything right but despite that the component's tag where the app should be mounted on stays empty. My files are as follow:

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: './public/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader!angular2-template-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
    },
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/typings/"
        ],
        "types": [
            "core-js"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Songs App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="./../dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
        <song-app></song-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

The App component element is `<song-app>`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './components/App.component';
import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        routingComponents
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**EDIT 2:**

**app.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'song-app',
    templateUrl: './App.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Song List App';
}
```

The template I'm using is just a simple div with the title variable inside.

Comment: Did you consider using angular-cli?

Comment: Can you add the AppModule code to the question, too?

Comment: @R.Richards Edited the question to include the app.module file as requested.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked for the AppComponent code. Can you add that, too?

Comment: @R.Richards Added that one as well.

Comment: Does your `app.component.html` using the `title` variable somewhere? Like `{{title}}`?

Comment: `F12` do you see any errors in the dev console?

Comment: @R.Richards Yes the html is using it inside an h3 tag nothing more. As for errors I get none, that's the part that bothers me most.

Comment: No errors... I almost want to see some errors at this point. Give the angular-cli a try. You can install it via npm, and it uses WebPack in the latest versions. This should really work, it's almost too simple not to.

Comment: Will give it a go then. Thank you for your time!

Comment: don't use angular-cli yet if you are new in angular2; you lost the control and there are a lot of things that neeede be completed, when angular-cli be in release candidate, then you can start use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after trying to trim down anything extra to pin point the cause I found that I was calling zone.js in the html file but I was missing the `/dist/` folder in the URL so it was never really calling zone, it opened a slew of other problems but now it actually gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector tag(`<song-app>`) should be placed above the line that loads bundle.js file because `<song-app>` element should be available to bundle.js to load your components template in it.

In your index.html :

```
 <body>
            <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/zone.js"></script>
            <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
            <song-app></song-app>
            <script src="./../dist/app.bundle.js"></script>

        </body>
```

Comment: I actually did that while searching for a solution and it might have contributed to the problem as well.